# Collaborators for projects

Tags: discussion

I'm wondering whether it is appropriate to seek collaborators for Mathematica-related projects on Mathematica Stack Exchange. For example, would it be appropriate to post a question describing a potential Mathematica application, and ask if there are any parties interested in working on the application? Or should that be restricted to chat room discussions, if at all?

Alternatively, are there ways to search for Exchange members based on location, interest and expertise to facilitate collaboration? Would it then be possible to PM potential collaborators directly?

Comment: 1. There's no PM functionality in SE, this is [by design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431). I'd personally prefer such discussions be confined to a chat room, but any programmming problem that comes up *might* be suitable for asking on main.

Comment: There's the chatroom, you can write about your ideas there.  It may or may not be successful.  [MATLink](http://matlink.org/) is a collaboration born on this site.  But I also made the [IGraph/M package](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM) and suggested that people contribute.  No one has.

Comment: Not appropriate on this site. You might try the Wolfram Community.

Comment: @Szabolcs I use igraph thorough R. I did not know you had IGraph/M package. I will definitely take a deeper look since this would be a nice way to compare Mathematica and R.

Comment: @Anton If you used my IGraphR package, I suggest you change to IGraph/M: it's much better.  It's faster and better integrated.  However, it doesn't cover all of igraph yet. It's a lot of work and I have little time.  If there's specific functionality you need that it doesn't yet have, let me know, and I'll prioritize it.  Though most of the work I do now on this project is contributions to the core igraph C library.  The current IGraph/M release already includes things that the R and Python igraph interfaces don't yet have, and more is coming.

Comment: @Anton In particular, the following is new compared to the R interface:  The Bliss library is updated to the latest version.  It supports directed graphs and vertex colouring.  It's much faster than Mathematica's (nauty based?) builtin for hard problems. Clique finding is much, much faster for all cliques (not maximal ones). It's also much faster than what's in Mathematica.  What's coming: a big update for the LAD isomorphism finder which will bring at least a 6x speedup due to better memory management, as well as algorithmic improvements. Some more clique finding speedups are also on the way.

Comment: @Szabolcs These points are really good to be aware of! I am going to compile graph-related things I have done or would like to do with graph-based recommenders and let you know.

Comment: Thanks all for the info and suggestions